# How to translate RNA to protein without BioPython library

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Is there any easy way to convert protein to RNA by using a dictionary and `.replace` function?

Also, I have no idea how to code all possible variants of the RNA and DNA code redundancy, which makes it possible to code one amino-acid, by the different RNA triplets.

I think, maybe it should be like that:

```
RNA = input("")
RNA_dictionary = {
  "GCA":"A", "GCC":"A", "GCG":"A", "GCU":"A",
  "UGC":"C", "UGU":"C", "GAC":"D", "GAU":"D",
  "GAA":"E", "GAG":"E", "UUC":"F", "UUU":"F",
  "GGA":"G", "GGC":"G", "GGG":"G", "GGU":"G",
  "CAC":"H", "CAU":"H", "AUA":"I", "AUC":"I",
  "AUU":"I", "AAA":"K", "AAG":"K", "UUA":"L",
  "UUG":"L", "CUA":"L", "CUC":"L", "CUG":"L",
  "CUU":"L", "AUG":"M", "AAC":"N", "AAU":"N",
  "CCA":"P", "CCC":"P", "CCG":"P", "CCU":"P",
  "CAA":"Q", "CAG":"Q", "AGA":"R", "AGG":"R",
  "CGA":"R", "CGC":"R", "CGU":"R", "CGG":"R",
  "AGC":"S", "AGU":"S", "UCA":"S", "UCC":"S",
  "UCG":"S", "UCU":"S", "ACA":"T", "ACC":"T",
  "ACG":"T", "ACU":"T", "GUA":"V", "GUC":"V",
  "GUG":"V", "GUU":"V", "UGG":"W", "UAC":"Y",
  "UAU":"Y", "UAG":"!", "UAA":"!", "UGA":"!"
}

reverse_translation = RNA_dictionary.replace #(Have no idea how to insert here the input RNA)
print (reverse_translation)
```

I know it all can be done by using just one function, from the BioPython. And maybe my way of learning bioinformatics and how to code in common is a bit weird. But this way I like and feel that I more really understand how the code works than just memorizing it like a poem.

Comment: How does a protein look (in textform) and which possible variants are available? Do you have an example?

Comment: I assume BioPython is open-source... You could look at how it does it

Comment: @jerik, it looks like a combination of the amino acids written by the letters.
VYSQR... etc. And the three stop codons, in my dictionary as a "!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keys of your dictionary to create a regular expression for *finding* the triplets. Then use the dictionary in the `re.sub` callback function to make the replacements:

```
regex = "|".join(RNA_dictionary.keys())
translation = re.sub(regex, lambda m: RNA_dictionary[m.group()], RNA)

print(translation)
```

Comment: I still don`t know how to make it output all of the combinations.
But while testing it I found the way how to invert dictionaries.

inv_dict = {v: k for k, v in ini_dict.items()}

Answer (score 0):

Once you inverted your `dict` with the `inv_dict = {v: k for k, v in ini_dict.items()}` you mentioned you can use this.

```
seq=""
for aa in prot:
    codon = inv_dict.get(aa)
    seq+=codon

print(seq)
```

It doesn't account for the redundancy, but keep in mind that even for a very small protein sequence, there are thousands of possible nucleotide sequences.

For example, for the protein sequence:

AlaProLysPheTrpIleCysAla

you have 6 * 4 * 2 * 2 * 1 * 3 * 2 * 4 = 2304 possible sequences.

Comment: Yeah, I understood this later, when I tried to calculate all possible reverse translations.
Then I looked at how people do it in the real project.  They`re looking for the most common codon that used for the coding amino acid. And these values are different from species to species.
That means at first you need a genome sequence and calculate the common codons for every aminoacids. And then use this table for reverse translation.

Comment: That's correct, that's the normal way to reverse translate. The other similar but different problem you may run into is to translate nucleotide sequences to aa (for example for better alignment) and then reverse translate to nucleotides based on the original sequence codons.